# Format of bumpmaps

Tags: unity, graphics

I have a height map I am generating in memory, just an array of floats from 0 to 1. I want to turn this into a bumpmap to be used in Unity3D. I believe I just need to create a Texture2D with the appropriate data in the RGB channels but I do not know what the format is for bump maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page of the Unity Manual explains the format: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterNormalMap.html

> The RGB colour values are used to store the X,Y,Z direction of the vector, with Z being “up” (contrary to Unity’s usual convention of using Y as “up”). In addition, the values in the texture are treated as having been halved, with 0.5 added. This allows vectors of all directions to be stored. Therefore to convert an RGB colour to a vector direction, you must multiply by two, then subtract 1. For example, an RGB value of (0.5, 0.5, 1) or #8080FF in hex results in a vector of (0,0,1) which is “up” for the purposes of normal-mapping - and represents no change to the surface of the model. This is the colour you see in the flat areas of the “example” normal map earlier on this page.

To convert your bump map into a normal map you take each pixels and compare their height to their neighbors in both X and Y direction.

You can use 2 neighbors in only one direction or average both sides (-1 and +1, shown below). Assuming a function texel(x,y) does proper wrap-around or clipping and returns the height of a texel, a cheap way to do it:

```
diff_x = Texel(x-1, y) - Texel(x+1, y);
diff_y = Texel(x, y-1) - Texel(x, y+1);

color.x = Clamp(diff_x * scale, -1, 1);
color.y = Clamp(diff_y * scale, -1, 1);
color.z = SquareRoot(1.0 - Clamp(color.x * color.x + color.y * color.y, 0, 1));

color = Normalize(color);

color = color * 0.5 + 0.5;
```

It's not quite right but it gives sharp edges and is quick to calculate.

The correct one uses

```
color.x = Normalize(Vec2(1, diff_x * scale)).y;
color.y = Normalize(Vec2(1, diff_y * scale)).y;
```

to calculate x & y properly.

Comment: I added a better option to calculate x & y (replace those two corresponding lines in the first example). The first example is much faster for doing water effects right on the GPU but the 2nd one is the correct one since you're probably pre-calculating it only once on the CPU at load time.